# Wscript .vbs file not running in task scheduler in windows 10

Tags: scheduler, wsh

I have a wscript to run a .vbs file on my desktop.  And I want it to run every day at a certain time.  I set up a task in the Windows 10 to run the script, but nothing happens at the designated time.  Under the "action" tab in the scheduler I have wscript.exe in the Program/Script: input line, and the file path in the Add Arguments line.  When I simply double click on the .vbs file on my desktop, it works just fine, but for some reason the task scheduler won't start it, even when I try clicking "Run" in the scheduler to test.  I've been reading on some forums that maybe it needs to be a cscript.exe, but I've tried that it doesn't work.  My .vbs file does use wscirpt, so maybe I need to change the script to cscript at the same time and rerun it.  I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work.  Below the script in my .vbs file.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"""

WScript.Sleep 3000

WshShell.AppActivate "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Sleep 5000

WshShell.SendKeys "XXXXX"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Sleep 5000

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Sleep 5000

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\carls\Desktop\REIT Model\Model Forward\Stock Model REITs.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Application.Run "PortfolioEvaluator"

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "outlook"

WScript.Sleep 30000

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"""

WScript.Sleep 3000

WshShell.AppActivate "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```